# question on diameter of open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Consider the usual metric $\mathit d$ for $\Bbb R$, where $\mathit d=|x-y|$$\forall$$\mathit x,y$∈$\Bbb R$. find the diameter of following sets

$\mathit (i)$$\Bbb A$=(-$\infty$,0)
$\mathit (ii)$$\Bbb B$=(0,$\infty$)
$\mathit (iii)$$\Bbb C$=(-$\infty$,$\infty$)

Here is my answer
d($\Bbb A$)$=$$\infty$$=$d($\Bbb B$) and d($\Bbb C$)=0.

Please anyone verify my answer and if it is wrong please help.

Comment: Considering that both $A,B$ were *unbounded* and had infinite diameter, and that $C$ is also *unbounded* (think what is implied by *bound*), you should be able to see why your answer to $C$ is wrong

Comment: Yes Sir..I understand your point. Thanks 

Comment: The diameter must never be smaller than any distance within the set. So $d(C)=0$ claims that for any two points in $\mathbb{R}$, the distance between them is at most zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb C$ is wrong and d($\Bbb C$)=$\infty$